# Troubles installing MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 server. I want to install MySQL 8.0 on it so I issued the following commands that I found on the web

```
 wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
 dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

After executing the dpkg command, I get a screen to choose the configuration that I want. Of course I choose MySQL 8.0. I expected to see something like this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-apt-config.
(Reading database ... 51260 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
```

but, I only saw this warning:

```
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
```

After that, I can only install MySQL 5.7 and not 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Removing, purging and reinstalling the mysql-apt-config package fixed this for me:

```
dpkg --remove mysql-apt-config
dpkg --purge mysql-apt-config
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me (and seems to not work for a lot of people).  I don't see the 8.0 option available, and still get the "Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)" message anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for me. 
Download the latest version of mysql, 0.8.10 is not enough.

- wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
- sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt install mysql-server